# Angular js Radio buttion part is not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS radio buttons, I'm trying to change the radio button, if I change the values are comming two to model.

Please have a look on the following code.

```
 <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="certResults.option1flag" ng-value="true">
 <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="certResults.option2flag" ng-value="true">
 <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="certResults.option3flag" ng-value="true">
 <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="certResults.option4flag" ng-value="true">
```

Comment: Please explain it a little bit more and write the code your using to achieve it.

Comment: Please provide the **minimal code to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: here i have four radio buttons and i selected first after that i changed to second radio button . i'm getting first and second options are coming to model..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to radio button to work properly:

- `ng-model` should be the same for all radio buttons
- `ng-value` should be different per radiobutton and reflect your `ng-model`

*HTML*

```
 <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="radio" ng-value="values[0]" />{{values[0]}}
 <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="radio" ng-value="values[1]" />{{values[1]}}
 <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="radio" ng-value="values[2]" />{{values[2]}}
 <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="radio" ng-value="values[3]" />{{values[3]}}
```

*JS*

```
 $scope.radio = 'aaa';   
 $scope.values = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'];
```

<kbd>[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9dzqoqw/)</kbd>

---

Hope it will help you

Comment: it is not updating dynamically

Comment: @manoharreddy do you want only one should be selected from 4?

Comment: radio button i select 1st and after that i select second ,inside model i' getting two values

Comment: @manoharreddy radio button is for 1 value selected. Do you mean checkbox?

Comment: No,I want radio buttons only. if i select multiple time other buttions from UI it is showing only one button is selected .in model class i'm getting multpile options are selected